# Trapping an error in a 3rd party component

Tags: c#, asp.net, bing-maps

I am using a 3rd party mapping component called [Simplovation](https://simplovation.com/default.aspx).  I have a dropdown listbox that selects a state within the country, and a Bing map is displayed.

The codebehind related to the map in the listbox is:

```
protected void VendorcontractDD_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.VendorcontractDD.SelectedIndex > -1 && Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
             VendorContract Vendorcontract = new Contract((Convert.ToInt32(VendorcontractDD.SelectedValue)));
             MainMap.Latitude = contract.GetLatitude();
             MainMap.Longitude = contract.GetLongitude();
             MainMap.Zoom = 8; //Set as a default when loading
             MainMap.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //throw ex;
    }
    finally
    { }
}
```

The aspx is:

```
<Simplovation:Map runat="server" ID="MainMap" Width="744px" EnableBirdseye="true"  
    Height="450px" AsyncPostbackPassShapes="true" EnableViewState="true"> 
</Simplovation:Map>
```

When I make a different selection from the listbox, I get an error message as shown below:

[image]

and the error occurs in the 3rd party component (shown below...can't seem to enlarge the image).
[image]

How would I go about trapping an error that occurs in a 3rd party component?

Comment: where are you actually creating an instance and or using the object..? can you show the code where you are making the call

Comment: How is MainMap Defined..? can you show all relevant code

Comment: `try-catch-finally`, anyone?

Comment: @Renan... tried that... doesn't work

Comment: show the code for the listbox event OnClick or OnChange which ever you are using

Comment: @Csharp - try-catch - in client-side JS code. Since the error obviously happens there.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter how would I do that clientside? Everything is being done serverside